# Excel for Mac grouping above the rows and to the left of columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

In Windows Excel, there is an option to group above the lines and to the left on the columns:

[image: Windows example]

I just installed Excel for Mac (latest 2020 version) and this option is missing in the Group section.
[image]
Do you know if it's possible to change the grouping direction in Mac? Seems crazy that this  feature was missed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is in the `Data` Menu item and can be seen here using Excel from my 365 Subscription

[image: Group Option]

[image: Settings Panel]

Comment: Thank you, that answered it!